# Vue - parent component needs to check the value of a prop in the child component before doing something (Conditional assignment)

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

i have this component, if `nav` is entered or leaved, i want to reassign `isNavClosed` to the opposite of its value so `nav` and `main` content get decreased and increased accordingly, but i only want to do that if hamburger menu is closed, in `nav` component i have ref `isHamburger` to express the state of hamburger menu, so in `enterLeaveNav` function i want to reassign `isNavClosed` ref only if ref `isHamburger` is true, therefore i need to check its value from `nav` child before reassigning it, how can i access the value of `isHamburger` from parent without actually moving it to the parent ?

```
<script setup>
import Header from "@/Components/Header.vue";
import Nav from "@/Components/Nav.vue";
import { ref } from "vue";

const isScroll = ref(false);
const isNavClosed = ref(false);

function setIsNavClosed() {
    isNavClosed.value = !isNavClosed.value;
}

function enterLeaveNav() {
    isScroll.value = !isScroll.value;
}
</script>


<template>
    <div>

        <!-- Page Heading -->

        <header class="header container">
            <Header />
        </header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row g-0">

        <!-- navigation component -->

                <nav
                    class="p-0 nav"
                    :class="[
                        isScroll ? 'overflowScroll' : 'overflowHidden',
                        isNavClosed ? 'width833' : 'width1633',
                    ]"
                    @mouseenter="enterLeaveNav"
                    @mouseleave="enterLeaveNav"
                >
                    <Nav @open-close-nav="setIsNavClosed" />
                </nav>

        <!-- Main content-->

                <main
                    class="ps-5"
                    :class="[
                        isNavClosed
                            ? 'offset-md-1 col-md-10'
                            : 'offset-md-2 col-md-9',
                    ]"
                    style="margin-top: 100px"
                >
                    <slot name="content" />
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

i tried to use composable to use these states accross child and parent component, but the problem is that when `nav` component mutate state, only `nav` component will be updated, but the parent will not be updated and the state will always be false:

`Composables/useNavigation.js`

```
import { ref } from "vue";

export function Navigation() {
    const isNavClosed = ref(false);
    const isHamburgerClosed = ref(false);
    const isScroll = ref(false);

    function toggleNav() {
        isNavClosed.value = !isNavClosed.value;
        isHamburgerClosed.value = !isHamburgerClosed.value;
    }

    function enterLeaveNav() {
        if (isHamburgerClosed.value) {
            isNavClosed.value = !isNavClosed.value;
        }
        isScroll.value = !isScroll.value;
    }

    return {
        isScroll,
        isNavClosed,
        isHamburgerClosed,
        toggleNav,
        enterLeaveNav,
    };
}
```

`Nav.vue`

```
    <div
        class="hamburgerMenu"
        :class="isHamburgerClosed ? 
        'hamburgerMenuMarginLeft2' :
        'hamburgerMenuMarginLeft80'"
        @click="toggleNav">
            <div class="hamburgerPiece"></div>
            <div class="hamburgerPiece"></div>
            <div class="hamburgerPiece"></div>
    </div>
```

`parent component`

```
<script setup>
import Header from "@/Components/Header.vue";
import Nav from "@/Components/Nav.vue";
import { Navigation } from "@/Composables/Navigation";

const { isScroll, isHamburgerClosed, isNavClosed, enterLeaveNav } =
    Navigation();
</script>
<!-- @open-close-nav="setIsNavClosed" -->
<!-- :class="[isNavClosed ? 'offset-md-1' : 'offset-md-2']" -->

<template>
    <div>
        <!-- Page Heading -->
        <header class="header container">
            <Header />
        </header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row g-0">
                {{ isHamburgerClosed }}
                <nav
                    class="p-0 nav"
                    :class="[
                        isScroll ? 'overflowScroll' : 'overflowHidden',
                        isNavClosed ? 'width833' : 'width1633',
                    ]"
                    @mouseenter="enterLeaveNav"
                    @mouseleave="enterLeaveNav"
                >
                    <Nav />
                </nav>
                <main
                    class="ps-5"
                    :class="[
                        isNavClosed
                            ? 'offset-md-1 col-md-10'
                            : 'offset-md-2 col-md-9',
                    ]"
                    style="margin-top: 100px"
                >
                    <slot name="content" />
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Just create composable that contains all the state info for your navigation components.

Comment: sounds like a global state management, i like it

Comment: but it doesn't work as the state updates in the child but not the parent

Comment: composables are not intended to be used as state management, its just a reusable functions that contains common logic between components

Comment: Vue documentation itself has an example of using a [composable to hold global state](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api:~:text=or%20even%20return%20global%20state%20from%20a%20Composable%3A). You should add the code for your attempt to your question so we can see what you tried and what might be wrong.

Comment: the problem is that parent doesn't get updated when the state changes, please check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you parent/child components aren't intended to use separately you probably should use `provide/inject` with the state in the parent component. I love it and use it always in parent-child components that are used only together:

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html

Also note that the global state is for business data. The UI state (expanded / collapsed) that lives only when its components are alive should be stored in the root component of a component hierarchy.

Comment: i have question, i have no experience and im worried about performance, if i use this parent as the layout of all components of my application, is that bad ? like if i update state that is dependency of that component will that cause my whole application to re-render ?

Comment: @ahmadkharabsheh vue uses virtual DOM so only DOM elements having updated data will be re-rendered: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/rendering-mechanism.html

Comment: lol, ok, you deserve it